# Get uniq values using filter in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to display only uniq values when I'm using filter

For example, I have this:

```
const test = 'This is Right';
const test1 = 'This is wrong';
const test2 = 'This is Right';
const test3 = 'The word is hello'

const result = [test, test1, test2, test3].filter(value => value).join(' - ');
console.log(result);
```

The output is:

```
This is Right - This is wrong - This is Right - The word is hello
```

What I want :

```
This is Right - This is wrong - The word is hello
```

I already see some same issues but I don't wanna work with array.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Yes I already see this but I don't wanna use array

Comment: `[test, test1, test2, test3]`  <-- this is an array

Comment: Yes it's true but then I filter to a string variable (result)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can get unique value using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const test = "This is Right";
const test1 = "This is wrong";
const test2 = "This is Right";
const test3 = "The word is hello";

const set = new Set().add(test).add(test1).add(test2).add(test3);
const result = [...set].join(" - ");
console.log(result);
```

**2)** Using Array literal with Set

```js
const test = "This is Right";
const test1 = "This is wrong";
const test2 = "This is Right";
const test3 = "The word is hello";

const set = new Set([test, test1, test2, test3]);
const result = [...set].join(" - ");
console.log(result);
```

**3)** Use with Array only

```js
const test = "This is Right";
const test1 = "This is wrong";
const test2 = "This is Right";
const test3 = "The word is hello";

const dict = [];
const result = [test, test1, test2, test3]
  .filter((value) => {
    if (!dict.includes(value)) {
      dict.push(value);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
  .join(" - ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works but if I don't wanna use "new Set"., they are no antoher possibilities ?

Comment: @ffzefzefzefzeff Added a solution using just array again

Answer (score 0):

You could use Set and initialize it with an array of strings

```
const test = 'This is Right';
const test1 = 'This is wrong';
const test2 = 'This is Right';
const test3 = 'The word is hello';

const m = new Set([test, test1, test2, test3])

console.log([...m].join(' - '))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works but if I don't wanna use "new Set"., they are no antoher possibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see this is short version of @decpk

```js
const test = "This is Right";
const test1 = "This is wrong";
const test2 = "This is Right";
const test3 = "The word is hello";

const result = [...new Set([test, test1, test2, test3])].join(" - ");
console.log(result);
```

As you can see this actually use array `[test, test1, test2, test3]` create a `Set` will delete duplicate then use `join` for create `string`.

---

You can use `filter` like:

```js
const test = "This is Right";
const test1 = "This is wrong";
const test2 = "This is Right";
const test3 = "The word is hello";

const result = [test, test1, test2, test3].filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index).join(" - ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works but if I don't wanna use "new Set"., they are no antoher possibilities ?

Comment: See my edit, i add filter method

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set for achieving this-

```
const uniqueValues = new Set();
uniqueValues.add(test);
uniqueValues.add(test1);
uniqueValues.add(test2);
uniqueValues.add(test3);

console.log("result - " , uniqueValues);
console.log("Result in form of String : ", Array.from(uniqueValues).join(' - '));
```

// Or without using set:-

```
const values = [test, test1, test2, test3];
let result = [];
result = values.filter((item, index) => {
    return values.indexOf(item) === index;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: No other possibilites without Set ?

Comment: Edited the answer. Both the ways are mentioned: with and without set. Have a look